# Eregi replace to?

Tags: php, eregi

can someone show me how to convert this please

```
eregi_replace(":rolleyes:", "<img src='./images/smilies/icon_rolleyes.gif' border='0'> ", $
```

i have tried lookin gonline but carnt get my head around it keep getting this error
keep getting

PHP Deprecated:  Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in

Comment: You do not need any regular expression replacements, a simple `str_replace()` will do the work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `eregi_replace` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.3. You should use `preg_replace` with the `i` modifier instead:

`preg_replace('/:rolleyes:/i', '<img src="./images/smilies/icon_rolleyes.gif" border="0">', $var);`